# Casting pointer to derived class to reference to pointer to base class

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, reference

Why I can't cast a pointer to derived class to reference to pointer to base class?

```
struct Base { };
struct Derived : Base { };

int main()
{
    Derived* derived = nullptr;
    static_cast<Base*&>(derived);
}
```

I get:

```
invalid static_cast from type 'Derived*' to type 'Base*&'
```

Comment: First of all, that `static_cast` has no effect, because you are not storing the return-value anywhere. Second, if you want to cast a `Derived*` variable to a `Base*` variable, then get rid of the `&`.

Comment: So it should be something like `Base* base = static_cast<Base*>(derived);`. However, with your current code at hand, it seems that you can simply do `Base* base = nullptr;`, since casting the `Derived*` variable is not going to change its value.

Comment: Is this an academic question, or do you have a real need for this cast?

Comment: No, it is not an academic question. I need to call a function taking as argument `Base*&`.

Answer (score 3):

As per your comment:

"No, it is not an academic question. I need to call a function taking as argument `Base*&`"

The correct way to resolve this is to create a new pointer variable of the appropriate type, and pass that (or rather, a reference to it) to the function in question:

```
struct Base { };
struct Derived : Base { };

int main()
{
    Derived* derived = nullptr;
    Base* base = static_cast<Base*>(derived);
    my_function(base); // takes a Base*& argument

    // If you need the pointer value and are sure that
    // it's a Derived* type:
    derived = static_cast<Derived*>(base);
}
```

Note that you would likely have received this answer sooner if you had included the pertinent information (from the comment I quoted above) in the question itself.

Comment: But in your solution `base` is modified by `my_function`, while `derived` is unchanged.

Comment: @RuggeroTurra that's right. A function which takes a `Base *&` parameter is not guaranteed to set the referent to a `Derived *` value. If you are certain that the pointer will be a `Derived *`, you can cast and assign it after the function completes. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Because a `Derived*` object is not a `Base*` object, and it's perfectly possible the two can have different memory layout or value representation (if the alignment requirements of `Base` and `Derived` differ, for example). Since one is not the other, `static_cast` is powerless to perform the conversion.

If you know what you're doing and know that the type pun is OK, use the tool for type punning — `reinterpret_cast`:

```
reinterpret_cast<Base*&>(derived);
```

And be aware of any consequences of misuse (as always goes with `reinterpret_cast`). Notice in particular that per C++11 3.10/10, any access through the result of the cast will be Undefined Behaviour as far as the standard is concerned (although your compiler might possibly give stronger guarantees).

Notice that in the general case, a cast from `Derived*` to `Base*` need not be a no-op. It can involve an address shift if multiple inheritance is involved, for example.

Comment: Type punning is the process of treating one type as another. A cast such as you mention doesn't actually involve type punning itself, since the object isn't de-referenced. (In other words, `reinterpret_cast` allows for type-punning, but using `reinterpret_cast` doesn't itself constitute type-punning).

Comment: @davmac Well, I sort of assume the OP is actually doing something with the result of the cast, which is in all likelihood a type pun. Sure, excatly as it stands, it's just a no-op.

Comment: In the example given by the OP (after chaging static_cast to reinterpert_cast as you suggest), doing anything with the result of the cast would break the aliasing rules, resulting in undefined behaviour. `Base *` and `Derived *` are incompatible types for access (3.10 paragraph 15 of the draft at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf).

Comment: @davmac That's a pretty ancient draft. 3.10/15 doesn't exist in published C++11 at all. The final draft of C++11 is [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), can you find a relevant reference there? What I have is 5.2.10/7,11, which makes the result unspecified. And as I said in the answer: "If you know what you're doing and know that the type pun is OK ..." Which your compiler docs can tell you, for example.

Comment: @Agnew In the draft you link, it's 3.10 paragraph 10 (it's commonly known as the _strict aliasing_ rule, and I can assure you it is present in one form or another in any recent version of the standard).

Comment: @davmac Thanks, updated the answer to (hopefully) make the warning even more severe.

Answer (score 1):

Extending on the answer provided by https://stackoverflow.com/users/1782465/angew-is-no-longer-proud-of-so, you can try this code to see why a reference to Base* (i.e. `Base*&`) can not bind to `Derived*`:

```
struct B {
    int valb;
};

struct D : B {
    int vald;
};

template<typename T>
struct SC {
    T vald_sc;
};

template<typename T>
struct MV {
    int valmv;
    T& valb;
    MV(T& vb) : valb(vb) {}
};

void f1(B* dp) {
}

void f2(B*& dp) {
}

void f3(B** dp) {
}

int main() {
    SC<D> sc;
    MV<B> mv(sc.vald_sc); //Conversion succeeds because a D object is a B object: their memory layout starts at the same addr

    SC<D*> scp;
    //MV<B*> mvp(scp.vald_sc); //Error: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'D *' to 'B *&' for 1st argument
    //NB: A D* object is not a B* object.
    MV<B*> mvp1(reinterpret_cast<B*&>(scp.vald_sc));
    MV<B*> mvp2(*reinterpret_cast<B**>(scp.vald_sc));

    f1(scp.vald_sc);
    f2(reinterpret_cast<B*&>(scp.vald_sc));
    f2(*reinterpret_cast<B**>(scp.vald_sc));
    f3(reinterpret_cast<B**>(&scp.vald_sc));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For your Error only
change this

```
static_cast<Base*&>(derived);
to 
static_cast<Base*>(derived);
                ^^
```

See here http://ideone.com/1QuMLK

Answer (score -1):

if you want a reference you need to do

```
Base* ptr = static_cast<Base*>(derived);
Base &ref = *ptr;
```

you cant cast a pointer to a reference - they are quite different things

Comment: "you cant cast a pointer to a reference" - not correct; you _can_ cast a "pointer to T" to a "reference to pointer to T". The result is a reference to the original pointer.